CheckConstraint in sqlalchemy not working as expected
I have been using this model for a sqlite3 server for a while where the CheckConstraint only had those first two lines and it seemed to be working fine. I wanted to allow another case represented in the third line of CheckConstraint where no constraint is imposed on title as long as published is false (relative to the first line). However, my requests are still failing. I've included an example from an error.
class Entity(db.Model): 
    __tablename__ = 'entities'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('users.id'), nullable=False)
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('entities.id'))
    published = Column(Boolean, nullable=False) # determines if draft
    artwork_path = Column(String) # can't be empty if no parent id
    title = Column(Text) # must be empty if has parent id
    body = Column(Text) # can't be empty if has parent id
    created_at = Column(TIMESTAMP, server_default=func.now())
    last_updated = Column(TIMESTAMP, onupdate=func.now())

    __table_args__ = (
        CheckConstraint(
            "(parent_id IS NULL AND title IS NOT NULL AND artwork_path IS NOT NULL) OR \ " 
            "(parent_id IS NOT NULL AND title IS NULL AND body IS NOT NULL) OR \ "
            "(published = false AND parent_id IS NULL AND artwork_path IS NOT NULL)",
            name="check_post_or_comment"
        ),
    )

And here is part of an error:
sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (sqlite3.IntegrityError) CHECK constraint failed: check_post_or_comment
[SQL: INSERT INTO entities (user_id, parent_id, published, artwork_path, title, body, last_updated) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) RETURNING id, created_at]
[parameters: (1, None, 0, '5897187d9ac149b2bc4450432f0f4b98.jpg', None, None, None)]
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/gkpj)


if the table already exists, then adding a constraint here will not change that, you will have to either drop and recreate (relatively easy) or have to migrate or manually run it

Thank you! I thought restarting the server would be enough but that makes sense now that i think about it
